# Document font instead of math font in chemical formula (mhchem package)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, chemistry, mhchem

I would like to write all chemical formulas in my document using the `mhchem` package which facilitates the use of the document font. It works quite nicely so far, but it fails for the letter "x".

This is how it should look like:

[image: correct]

This is the result using `\ce{NO_x}`:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to use the document font (and not the math font) for the letter x in chemical formulas?

Interestingly, though, it does work for uppercase letters:

[image]

Comment: Note that the _x_ shall be italic, see: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/proper-typography-of-nox

Comment: @yo' is right. The IUPAC recommendations are very clear. It also fits the general rule: variables are typeset in italics. But if you insist: `\ce{NO_{\text{x}}}`

Comment: Or use `chemformula` instead of `mhchem` and use `\ch{NO_x}` (the *correct* input then would be `\ch{NO_{$x$}}` which means it requires a little more thinking and typing of the user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ce{NO_{\text{x}}}` does the trick!

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \ce{NO_{\text{x}}}
\end{document}
```

BUT: [The *x* shall be italic!](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20315/proper-typography-of-nox)

Comment: Thank you - even though it is not necessary any more for my case, it could be useful for other users.

Comment: @Sr. Schneider: I get the `x` in roman.

Comment: @Bernard when you use `\ce{NO_x}`?

Comment: @clemens: No – using `\ce{NO_\text{x}` or `\ce_\mathrm{x}` .

Comment: @Bernard that's the expected output. (I get errors with `\ce{NO_\text{x}}` but `\ce{NO_{\text{x}}}` compiles fine)

Answer (score 3):

1. For correct typesetting, it should be italic. See the other answers and comments with links. **Leave as is and you are correct.**

This is a feature of rather recent versions of mhchem.

2. You do not get math font!

`\ce{NO_x}` will render NO in upright text font and x in italic text font. Try another text font (for instance \sffont) and you'll see. Put the command into a headline and everything will look as it should be.

On the other hand, if you use mhchem in math mode like `$\ce{NO_x}$`, this will render NO in upright math font and x in italic math font.

3. If you really need a supscript with an upright x, you *could* write `\ce{A_{\text{x}}}` as others suggested. However, this will force text font and therefore is not recommended in math mode (unless the fonts really match well). The *preferred* way is to write `\ce{A_{{x}}}` as this will result in correct fonts, regardless whether used inside or outside of math mode.
4. All of this is explained in the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf). But who reads manuals in the age of StackExchange?

Comment: I searched the manual for an official way but I didn't get that `{…}` gives upright text (depending on the  surrounding font settings) the first time :/ Thinking about it now it's rather obvious, though.